# Change textColor in list view item programmatically

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin.forms

I want to do something like this:

```
 textLabel_inCell.TextColor = Color.Black;
```

but Visual Studio shows an error:

"textLabel_inCell doesn't exist in the current context!"

How can I change text color of listView item programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, textLabel really doesn't exist as there is no single textLabel but rather many of them in the `ListView`.

In general this is done with data binding: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-binding-basics#bindings-and-collections

Comment: You can't, look at the sample.

Comment: hmmmmm..... so I can't change text color in listView programmatically? In the sample I didn't find anything useful for me

Comment: There is no difference in setting textcolor to setting the text. I believe you know the latter. If you don't know then read that document from the start and if you still don't know then read documentation further. Those are very basics of Xamarin.Forms and can't be explained in one answer.

Comment: Also if you want to set it one time you may want to create the custom ViewCell, then you can use the code behind.

Comment: I've made suggestions. Unfortunately you need to go through tutorials and learn things, no one can do that for you, it is not that you miss a line or two in your knowledge.

Comment: Holy........  Is this so hard ???? Is it hard to just change text color of label in view cell in that was in xaml programmatically????? Is this so hard?????

Comment: If you haven’t learned all the letters and you are trying to write the novel it is going to be very hard.

Answer (score 0):

In case of changing Xaml values programmatically either use **Converters** or **Triggers** .

Answer (score -3):

Simply, you can try this:

listView1.Items[0].SubItems[0].BackColor= Color.Violet;

Just do your own customization stuff for item index (0) as your need.

I hope this can help you bro ^_^

***     More Clarifying     ***
I meant this brothers,

[image]

and here you the code:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.Items[2].BackColor = Color.Red;
    }
```

Comment: There is no such API: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Xamarin.Forms.ListView?view=xamarin-forms#fields

Comment: He is asking for xamarin form, not window form

Comment: As @Lee told that he is asking for xamarin help but window form application